# Open a Folder in Firefox Addon: Why Not Working?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, add-on

This used to open a directory inside my addon (../extension/value@my.name/sample_profile, but now it doesn't... I'm sure something has changed in FF, but not sure what is broken here.

```
  function open_blankProfile()
    {

      var MY_ID = "value@my.name";

      var stream = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/network/file-input-stream;1"]
                         .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIFileInputStream);
      var directoryService = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/directory_service;1"]
                         .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIProperties);

      var em = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/extensions/manager;1"].
             getService(Components.interfaces.nsIExtensionManager);

      var profile_directory = em.getInstallLocation(MY_ID).getItemFile(MY_ID, "sample_profile");

      var localFile = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/local;1"]
                              .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsILocalFile);
      localFile.initWithPath(profile_directory.path);

        try {
          localFile.reveal();
        } catch(ex) {
          var uri = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/network/io-service;1"]
                              .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIIOService)
                              .newFileURI(localFile);

          var protSvc = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/uriloader/external-protocol-service;1"]
                                  .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIExternalProtocolService);
          protSvc.loadUrl(uri);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because, since Firefox 4, [extensions are not automatically unpacked](http://mdn.beonex.com/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIInstallLocation.html)

Comment: I should have noted that mine is already unpacked -- I suspect that it has something to do with some of the nsI calls changing.